# Is there a book or notes that explain all about inflation?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, reference-request, inflation, self-study

Is there a book or notes or papers (but for easy understanding please) that explain all about inflation?

Not at a research level but student level.

From what is previously needed to define and understand inflation,  to calculate inflation, to models to analyze inflation, how does inflation impacts economic agents (firms, families, etc), and other things that should be known about inflation too.

So far I haven't find a book nor PDF notes that mentions all these. I've encountered helpful youtube videos but most of them don't say where is that information from, nor is rigorous, yet are helpful because they gave you an idea of what's going on.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking something for student level the best place to start are textbooks. You will not generally find these just for single topic such as inflation (for that you would have to look at research papers but you explicitly state you are not looking for that) but they offer rigorous treatment with references to the literature.

Mankiw Macroeconomics Chapter 5 gives nice undergraduate introduction to  inflation, for more full undergraduate treatment you can have look at Lewis and  Mizen Monetary Economics.

Walsch Monetary Theory and Policy offers graduate level treatment of many models including inflation. In fact virtually all models there involve inflation in one way or another.

You could supplement Walsch also with Romer Advanced Macroeconomics or with Woodford Interest and Prices.

Comment: Ok, I'll check them, Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about  PDF notes also?

Comment: @veronikaRmz. I dont know about pdf notes that would cover this in such great lengths as the textbooks, however, I know for a fact that if you know how to use internet you will be able to find pdf versions of almost all of these books for free, I cant give you links as I would potentially expose myself to copyright violations, and I dont condone or encourage piracy, but they are not that hard to find once you know the name of the books

Comment: I'm not looking for these for free, if they sell them they sell them. I'd not try to get them other ways.